# Auth::user() returns null with CORS requests between Laravel and Ionic

Tags: php, cross-domain

I'am trying to make ajax request on cross domain and not able to get session data it always return Null

I have set following parameter in ajax call client side

1) `withCredentials` to true

2) `crossdomain` to true

And server side

```
headers->set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', $origin);
headers('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Accept, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Language, Content-Length, Content-Type');
headers('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'DELETE, GET, PATCH, POST, PUT');
headers('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', 'true');
```

In config/session i have set `'domain' => 'http://localhost:8100'`,
But still no success.